# Is required that the pointers to two different local empty objects compare as unequal?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider the following methods:

```
typedef struct {} empty;
typedef struct { char x; } onechar;

void sink2(void* left, void* right);

void pass2empties() {
    empty e1, e2;
    sink2(&e1, &e2);
}

void pass2chars() {
    onechar e1, e2;
    sink2(&e1, &e2);
}

int check2empties() {
    empty e1, e2;
    return (&e1 == &e2);
}

int check2chars() {
    onechar e1, e2;
    return (&e1 == &e2);
}

unsigned sizeofempty() {
    return sizeof(empty);
}
```

I noticed that `clang` and `icc` pass identical addresses for `&e1` and `&e2` in `pass2empties`. Is this behavior allowed?

In the case of `clang` you have very weird behavior for the function:

```
int passAndCheck() {
    empty e1, e2;
    empty *left = &e1, *right = &e2;
    sink2(left, right);
    return (left == right);
}
```

It passes identical pointers to `sink2`, yet returns 0 for the direct comparison. So you have the case that both `left == right` and `left != right` for the same `left` and `right`. Is this allowed?

Assembly [can be seen here](https://godbolt.org/g/K9Gi7G).

Comment: What does `sink2` do?

Comment: Please post a MCVE showing the output you believe to be anomalous

Comment: @M.M - the anomalous output for the last case is in godbolt, linked at the bottom. For the other cases, I'm not sure if the output is anomalous at all.

Comment: Isn’t an empty struct already illegal?

Comment: @Ry- thanks, this was news to me! (Used to C++ where this is allowed).

Comment: gcc and clang both give warnings about the struct when using `-W -Wall -pedantic`.  icc, unfortunately, does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `typedef struct {} empty;` contains a syntax error. The grammar for `struct` declarations in C11 6.7.2.1/1 requires that the braces contain a *struct-declaration-list*, which is not optional.

As such, a conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic and the behaviour of the program is not defined by the standard.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be a gcc extension that all of `gcc`, `clang` and `icc` accept without a diagnostic, even with `-ansi` mode.

Comment: I believe you need `-pedantic` to get conforming mode